# Grails unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm currently trying to write some unit tests for my grails application. When i run the tests i get

```
    Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed:
    C:\Users\adam\Dropbox\NetBeansProjects\Assignment\test\unit\Assignment\FixtureControllerTests.
    groovy: 20: Only classes and closures can be used for attribute 'value' in  
    @grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
      @ line 20, column 12.
       @TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
```

I can't figure out why i am getting this error.
My code is:

```
    package Assignment

    import grails.test.mixin.Mock
    import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
    import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin

    @TestFor(FixtureController)
    @Mock(Fixture)
    @TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)


    class FixtureControllerTests {

        @Test
        public void testAddingFixture() {

            params.hometeamid = 1
            params.awayteamid = 2
            params.linkCount = 1
            params.link0 = "http://www.google.com"
            params.name0 = "Google"
            params.place = "Rotherham"
            params.date = new Date()
            controller.createFixture()

       }
   }
```

Comment: That does seem strange, what version of grails are you running?

Comment: You don't need `@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)` if you are using `@TestFor` for this test.

Comment: I'm using grails 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how test should look like:

```
package assignment //considering lowercase for package name

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(FixtureController)
@Mock(Fixture) //Assuming Fixture is a domain object you are working with
class FixtureControllerTests {

    void testAddingFixture() {
        params.hometeamid = 1
        params.awayteamid = 2
        params.linkCount = 1
        params.link0 = "http://www.google.com"
        params.name0 = "Google"
        params.place = "Rotherham"
        params.date = new Date()

        controller.createFixture()

        //assert something
    }
}
```

I believe you are using Grails 2.2.* or less and the template used for test in those version had `TestMixin`, which later on was replaced by `TestFor` in newer versions. Recent versions use spock by default.